# Using Git and Yarn Package.json script

Tags: git, cmd, yarnpkg

I'm creating a `package.json` script to send `git add .` `git commit -m "update"` `git push` using yarn

I tried sending the code above in sequence using one line but git doesn't understand it as different commands

What I want to achive:

```
"scripts": {
     "push": "git add . git commit -m \"update\" git push"
}
```

```
yarn push // should send script above
```

Is it possible to send more then one git command on terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your yarn script is spawning a shell process under the hood, so basically you have to use the same syntax you would use directly via the shell.

In most shells you use the && to chain commands, i.e && lets you do something based on whether the previous command completed successfully - that's why you tend to see it chained as do_something && do_something_else_that_depended_on_something

So here your solution would be:

```
"push": "git add . && git commit -m \"update\" && git push"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send multiple commands to the terminal by using the `&` or `&&` separators. Using the double `&&` will prevent the next command from running unless the first was successful.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "push": "git add . && git commit -m \"update\" && git push"
  }
}
```

On a side note, you can also merge the add and commit into a single command, `git commit -am "update"` will add and commit all changes.